# dcast in r with duplicates and no aggregation

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have looked through many similar questions here but can't find an answer that addresses this situation. My data frame is like this:

```
SET SP   T1  T2  T3
A   dog  1  0   0
A   cat  0  NA  4
A   bird 5  0   NA
B   cat  2  0   0
B   bird NA 3   0
C   dog  1  0   0
C   cat  0  0   6
C   bird 0  0   0
D   dog  NA 22  1
```

Where SET is purposefully duplicated many times, with each record including a single SP and values for multiple TRIALS (T1-3).

What I desire is a wide dataframe like the following. There is to be NO summation/averaging/mathematical operation of any kind:

```
SET DOG_T1  DOG_T2  DOG_T3  CAT_T1  CAT_T2  CAT_T3  BIRD_T1 BIRD_T2 BIRD_T3
142   1     0       0      0        NA      4       5       0       NA
255  NA     NA     NA      2        0       0       NA      3       0
336   1     0      0       0        0       6       0       0       0
66   NA    22      1       NA       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

I have tried the following, but receive the error with melt and dcast defaulting to length. This turns the SET variable into different numbers  and only fills in 0s and 1s for the value.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(SET, SP) %>% 
  melt(id.vars = c('SET','SP')) %>%
  data.table::dcast(SP + variable ~ SET, fun.aggregate = NULL, value.var = 'value')
```

This works when I DON'T have any duplicate SETs, but fails as soon as I include the full dataset.
A note: my real data frame is about 2.5 million rows, so speed is of concern.

Answer (score 2):

This is a situation where `dcast.data.table` excels. It allows for multiple arguments as 'value.var', allowing for very concise syntax:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(df, SET ~ SP, value.var=c("T1", "T2", "T3"))
#   SET T1_bird T1_cat T1_dog T2_bird T2_cat T2_dog T3_bird T3_cat T3_dog
#1:   A       5      0      1       0     NA      0      NA      4      0
#2:   B      NA      2     NA       3      0     NA       0      0     NA
#3:   C       0      0      1       0      0      0       0      6      0
#4:   D      NA     NA     NA      NA     NA     22      NA     NA      1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this still results in the "defaulting to length" error. I tried it both before and after the melt() step I placed above. I agree that dcast should be able to work here (from what I've read), but can't seem to get it to happen.

Comment: That is not an error, it is a warning. There are duplicates in the data. What would you like to do when there are two entries with Set A and T1 and bird?

Comment: As you can see above, there is only one slot for that entry, that is what a summary does. Would you like the values summed? averaged? etc...

Answer (score 1):

As per @lukeA above but add `fun.aggregate = identity` or `fun.aggregate = list` argument in `dcast()` function call

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.table(header=T, text="
SET SP   T1  T2  T3
A   dog  1  0   0
A   cat  0  NA  4
A   bird 5  0   NA
B   cat  2  0   0
B   bird NA 3   0
C   dog  1  0   0
C   cat  0  0   6
C   bird 0  0   0
D   dog  NA 22  1")
df %>% 
  gather(var, val, -(1:2)) %>% 
  unite("SP", SP, var) %>% 
  spread(SP, val)
#   SET bird_T1 bird_T2 bird_T3 cat_T1 cat_T2 cat_T3 dog_T1 dog_T2 dog_T3
# 1   A       5       0      NA      0     NA      4      1      0      0
# 2   B      NA       3       0      2      0      0     NA     NA     NA
# 3   C       0       0       0      0      0      6      1      0      0
# 4   D      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     22      1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In your example, are 'var' and 'val' the variable and value outcomes of the melt statement I described above, or something else?

Comment: var is the variable and contains t1 to t3, val is the value in the corresponding column.

Comment: Update: I was able to get this to run, but it threw an error regarding my duplicate identifiers in SET. This was solved by changing your last line from spread() to reshape: `df %>% 
  gather(var, val, -(7:8)) %>% 
  unite("SP", SP, var) %>% 
  reshape(idvar = 'SET', timevar =  'SP', direction = 'wide')`

Answer (score 0):

Since my current reputation doesn't allow adding a comment to @lukeA answer above, I am making this a new answer which is more of a suggestion:

using the `data.table` function `setcolorder` one could have the columns reordered as "bird_T1, cat_T1, dog_T1, bird_T2, cat_T2 etc." by using a custom function similar to

```
newOrder <- function() {

      lapply(1:max(index)
             , function(i) grep(
                                 sprintf('%s', i)
                                           , names(DT), value = TRUE)
        )}
```

where `index` is the index created in order to allow `dcast.data.table` for duplicated keys such as the SET variable in the initial table above:

```
DT[, index := 1:.N, by = SET]
```

finally the new order is achieved in regular manner:

```
setcolorder(dcast(DT), neworder = newOrder())
```